2D array and java.awt
So I wrote a program that takes in a txt file, converts it into a 2d array of a MazeCell enumeration(an enumeration I wrote of wall, person, space, exit, and start, represented by W's, E's, X's, P's and " "'s), finds a path and prints out the maze with W's, E's, ETC. Everything is working and running correctly but I wanted to change the output so that instead of W's, E's, etc, it would print out colors and graphics. I know I would need to import java.awt for this but I have no idea how to set it up.
